# Active state not working in Bootstrap menu

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem with navigation in Boostrap, I use the class="active" on mynavbar and it does not switch when I press menu, soactive state is not working in Bootstrap menu, I don't have any more ideas so please help.

Thanks.
Here is the code:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

  <title>Villa Maro</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/villa maro logo.png">
          </a>
        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Naslovna</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="smjestaj.html">Smjestaj</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="galerija.html">Galerija</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="rezervacija.html">Rezervacija</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I tested it and it worked in my computer. Post your `style.css` file, or check maybe you have something in this file that overrides Bootstrap's css?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
       $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
       $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
```

Add this short piece of code for take to work.

Answer (score 0):

The `class=active` need to be set depending on the page you are. I don't know what framework or so you are using but normally a value from a controller comes back to the template to set which item get the `active` class.

You obviously can set this via Javascript, as shown but this is probably not what you want I suppose.

Without further details of the application/framework you are using there is no possibility to help you further.